# How do we call the approach to unit test through an additional layer of abstraction?

Tags: unit-testing

There‘s an approach in unit testing where, instead of just writing the technical details in every test method, you create a **library of helper functions** like

- `givenServiceFails` (that acts on mock behavior)
- `whenUserDataIsRequested` (acting on the production code) and
- `thenDataIsDisplayed` (asserting mocks or production code)

Instead of having all the implementation details in the test methods, **you call those helper methods** that contain the implementation details.

Please note, this is **not** about BDD. BDD is not a test framework, it's a communication framework for tech and business people that results in runnable specification (Gherkin).

It only shares certain benefits with Gherkin-Libraries like Cucumber. E.g.:

- It has the benefit that you can reuse those helper methods in multiple test methods
- It adds a layer of abstraction over the production code that makes the test business easier to understand
- As the test methods are decoupled from the implementation details (interaction with production code, mocks and assertions), those implementation details becomes easier to change (maintainability).

**How do you call that approach to abstract the business of the test from the implementation details?** A natural naming for that approach for me would be „testing API“, but it‘s too similar to „test API“, which is a mock implementation of a „real“ API. The best I could guess would be "test abstraction layer" or the like.

My aim is to find references to that approach so I can correctly outline pros and cons of it and finally write about it. If I don't have the proper name for the approach, it's hard to engage in communication about it.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a specific name for this.

Comment: This is not something I would consider to be useful for unit tests, although I might have a different definition. To me, a unit test is not something that requires a database, file system, Web service, or anything else outside of the thread running the test.

Comment: A single unit test should run in 1ms or less. Did you have a different definition? Because I've seen this before with end-to-end tests, although I've never seen consensus on a name.

Comment: I think this is how BDD was originally intended to be done. Before it got hijacked for end-to-end Cucumber tests.

Comment: This is just ordinary refactoring.

Comment: My question is not about the usefulness, performance or place of application. Also it has nothing to do with Cucumber/BDD. It‘s concerned with unit tests and how they are structured and whether there‘s a name for that approach. My research lead nowhere so far…

Comment: Building the tests so they express expected behavior of the system is exactly what BDD is meant to be. For exactly the reason that it makes the tests explainable to business-focused people. BDD being about end-to-end and Cucumber is something it's original authors didn't intend to.  https://www.youtube.com/shorts/f3XqF-bVBm4

Comment: @GregBurghardt - but the question doesn't say that db / fs / external service is required for the test (although the naming in these helper method examples might suggest that). E.g. `givenBackendReturnsTrue` is just a name for the setup step that configures the mock prior to the assert. It can be useful as it makes the test more concise (given the name is sufficiently descriptive, and if the test is written in a robust way, so that the minute details of the test setup aren't important), as it lets you focus on the behavior being tested.

Comment: I would simply call this "write my own testing framework", though this can be misleading, since by "testing framework", one can also mean a tool like JUnit or NUnit or Xunit itself. So why not simply give your testing helper library a fancy name like "MyTestHelpersLib"  and use that name whenever you like to speak about it?

Comment: dunno how this gets closed for "opinion based" when I find two sensible seeming answers and @basilevs finds an exact match all with links

Comment: I think the question is not opinion seeking. I'm looking for an exact name of an approach. I'd be grateful if we could reopen it and give it more time. I refined my question in order to help the process.

Comment: The problem with questions about "naming things" is that there is no canonical, authoritative list of names. As a result, people tend to shout out a bunch of ideas, all of which could be equally correct. As a result, it becomes a list of opinionated answers with no reference to anything official, and no consensus on which name best fits. Occasionally there is a canonical name. These questions are hit-or-miss, because most things don't have an agreed-upon name, and therefore the question is opinion-based. Not a *bad* question, though. Just not a good fit for the Q&A style of this community.

Comment: If theres one thing software engineers do well its thinking up names for stuff. There are books of patterns and lists of methodologies. there are 100s of questions along the lines of "is this REST/BDD/DDD/Scrum/Agile/Singleton/etc

Comment: OK the reason why I posted my question is exactly because I don‘t want to shout out an arbitrary name. My hope was that some „highly regarded individuals“ already came up with a name. What‘s a better place for that question? Just frankly asking… Reddit?

Comment: Reddit or Quora do indeed have relaxed requirements for questions. They do not have comprehensive knowledge base as a goal.

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach you outline comes from BDD/Gherkin style testing.

When you write your BDD tests in plain language..

```
Given the home page is loaded
When the user clicks on login
Then A login form is displayed
```

You then have to actually write code to implement those steps and tests. Invariably you end up with methods which match the language of the tests

```
LoadHomePage()
ClickLogin()
AssertLoginFormDisplayed()
```

Given that BDD lends it's to reuse of the steps, these methods also see lots of reuse across your tests.

There is another pattern in unit testing called [ObjectMother](https://wiki.c2.com/?ObjectMother) which you might be thinking of.

This is Where you apply similar techniques to your test data eg

```
var target = TestData.Pages.HomePage().WhenNotLoggedIn();
```

or maybe even

```
var target = TestData.Pages.HomePage().WhenNotLoggedIn();
target.ClickLogin();
```

depending on how far you want to take it.

Comment: "This is where you apply similar techniques to your test data" - I just wanted to add (or clarify), it's not necessarily plain data classes (though that's probably very common), Object Mother could also produce a preconfigured object that implements some behavior, or a preconfugured (or partially configured) mock.

Comment: if you read to the end you will see i give an example where methods are called

Comment: I agree there are similarities, but I'm looking for the umbrella term. I updated my question to make it more clear what I meant. Sorry if I didn't put it clear enough.

Comment: I think the PageObject pattern is a correct answer, seems to match everything you describe

Comment: "if you read to the end ..." - that's true. Don't get me wrong, I think it's a good answer (got a +1 from me), just wanted to explicitly mention this for the benefit of any readers who might be less experienced. Also I was thinking of a slightly different situation - e.g, the obtained object might be a dependency to the instance under test (or a parameter to the method being tested), so the behavior I'm talking about might entirely play out within the call made in "act" step (that is, in the top level test code, there may be no methods called on the obtained instance prior to it being used).

Answer (score -1):

This is [PageObject](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html) pattern.

The idea is to wrap an object under test in an utility layer useful for testing.

The object under test can be domain object, a web page, database, UI dialog, anything. The name is a bit misleading as it is applied outside of webdev, to small controls, to whole applications, not only to web pages.

Usually PageObject operates on a higher abstraction level then than underlying object - it turns clicks into navigation, DB results into lists, dialogs with multiple inputs into methods with multiple arguments, multiple operations into scenarios, etc.

Comment: I won't downvote, but this is not the PageObject pattern (which is a similar idea, but it's at a slightly lower lever compared to what the OP is asking about, and the motivation is different). Also, the name doesn't make sense in the context the OP is describing (even given your disclaimer).

Comment: really? I thought this was spot on??

Comment: The PageObject pattern is a subset of what I'm searching for. But thanks for the answer! I didn't downvote. I think it's one step in the right direction.

Comment: It's not the page object pattern because the function that calls `whenUserDataIsRequested` and `thenDataIsDisplayed` doesn't need to know what pages the requests and displays are done on, or even if they are on pages. They could be on a CLI interface, or if we stretch the meaning of Displayed a conversational interface (e.g. Alexa skill or chatbot), without any need to change the code in the actual test file.

Comment: @bdsl that sounds exactly like the PageObject pattern as described in the link? "I've described this pattern in terms of HTML, but the same pattern applies equally well to any UI technology"

Comment: @Ewan I don't think it's quite the same. Fowler writes "... have an album list page object containing several album page objects. There would probably also be a header page object and a footer page object." . Implying that the code depending on page objects needs to be aware of the existence of headers, footers and album list pages containing album pages. I think the pattern the OP is asking about is one where even that information is abstracted away.

Comment: That is abstraction though? also the very next line: "That said, some of the hierarchy of a complex UI is only there in order to structure the UI - such composite structures shouldn't be revealed by the page objects. The rule of thumb is to model the structure in the page that makes sense to the user of the application."

Comment: @Ewan Yep, but you're still modelling the concept of pages. You're saying "please check that you can see the data, I don't care whether you have to navigate to a different page to see it". If you have an object it would represent the entire system, not any one page.

Comment: I mean I know MF is always throwing in "get out clauses" for any statement, but PageObject seems to perfectly match the idea of abstracting the detail of the UI from the test. Just compare his example methods "selectAlbumWithTitle, getArtist, updateRating" with the OPs examples

Comment: You need the level of abstraction that you want to test. For a webapp changing pages is critical so it's centered around the page. But he's got pages returning other pages on navigation, so it _is_ the whole app

Comment: If I would call my **testing helper frameworK" a "Page Object" in my team, I am sure noone will ever know what this means. Sorry, PageObject is a name which only fits to the abstraction of pages in web development, which is not the OP's case.

Comment: @DocBrown there are plenty of bad names for design patterns. It does snot make them unusable. Explain to your team, what terms are using and share some links.